# Facebook Like Button not working, shows weird error

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have had the Facebook like button for a long time on my website, but now its showing an error when someone clicks "like", the error says this.
The page failed to provide a valid list of administrators. It needs to specify the administrators using either a "fb:app_id" meta tag, or using a "fb:admins" meta tag to specify a comma-delimited list of Facebook users.

But I have added the fb:admins tag, it has always been there with my admin id.

It works on any other of my websites.

you can try it yourself here, press like and the error shows up :(
inhaltsangabe.info/bwl/kg-kommanditgesellschaft-lernzettel-fuer-abitur

Comment: Take a look at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.inhaltsangabe.info%2Fbwl%2Fkg-kommanditgesellschaft-lernzettel-fuer-abitur and at you sourcecode some options are defined multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Finhaltsangabe.info%2Fbwl%2Fkg-kommanditgesellschaft-lernzettel-fuer-abitur

> **Errors That Must Be Fixed**
>
> More Than One OG URL Specified:   Object at URL
>   'http://www.inhaltsangabe.info/bwl/kg-kommanditgesellschaft-lernzettel-fuer-abitur'
>   of type 'article' is invalid because it specifies multiple 'og:url'
>   values: 
>   http://www.inhaltsangabe.info/bwl/kg-kommanditgesellschaft-lernzettel-fuer-abitur,
>   http://www.inhaltsangabe.info/bwl/kg-kommanditgesellschaft-lernzettel-fuer-abitur.

Comment: Inferred Property: The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property: The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property: The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property: The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.